# How to check if element exists in DOM in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, selenium, cypress

I want to know how to check if an element exists in the DOM of a web page in Cypress.

What would the equivalent of this piece of code in Selenium be in Cypress:

```
Boolean Display = driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator")).isDisplayed();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query with an xpath locator, install the [cypress-xpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-xpath) extension.

> **Install with npm**
> `npm install -D cypress-xpath`
>
> **Install with Yarn**
> `yarn add cypress-xpath --dev`

In the test

```js
cy.xpath(locator)            // driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator"))
```

Add a visibility check as well,

```js
cy.xpath(locator)            // driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator"))
  .should('be.visible')      // isDisplayed()
```

or

```js
cy.xpath(locator)            // driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator"))
  .should('not.be.hidden')   // isDisplayed()
```

Comment: Would I be able to do this?:
var exists = cy.xpath(locator).should('be.visible')  //true or false

Comment: If your xpath locator incorporates the [count()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/count) method, you can test the value like this `cy.xpath(locator-with-count).then(count => { const exists = !!count; ...`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question, I don't get why there's no solution to implement this in a much simpler way like in Selenium.

Comment: In Cypress you're not supposed to extract values out of the command chain, because it can break the retry mechanism (which Selenium does not have).

Answer (score 10):

1.To check element exists in the DOM:

```
cy.get(selector).should('exist')
```

2.To check that the element doesn't exist in DOM:

```
cy.get(selector).should('not.exist')
```

3.To check that element is visible:

```
cy.get(selector).should('be.visible')
```

4.To check that element is not visible:

```
cy.get(selector).should('not.be.visible')
```

5.Using JQuery:

```
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
    if ($body.find(selector).length > 0) {
        //element exists do something
    }
})
```